# error in using mrdivide

Tags: matlab

i have found this code from the internet,on running the code the output shows correctly but i am still getting an error which is creating an issue while using the code with java.

Here is the code:

```
file_name='lena.bmp'; 
cover_object=double(imread(file_name)); 
mc=size(cover_object,1); 
nc=size(cover_object,2); 
file_name='dmg2.bmp'; 
message=double(imread(file_name)); 
mm=size(message,1); 
nm=size(message,2); 
[ca,ch,cv,cd]=dwt2(cover_object,'haar'); 
ca1=ca; 
qiangdu=1; 
for i=1:nm 
    for j=1:nm 
        if(message(i,j)==0) 
            ca1(i,j)=ca(i,j)+qiangdu; 
        end 
    end 
end 
watermarked_image=idwt2(ca1,ch,cv,cd,'haar'); 
watermarked_image_round=round(watermarked_image); 
watermarked_image_uint8=uint8(watermarked_image_round); 
imshow(watermarked_image_uint8);  
figure(2) 
imshow(watermarked_image_uint8,[]) 
title('watermarked image') 
imwrite(watermarked_image_uint8,'dwt_watermarked.bmp','bmp'); 
xsz=mc*nc*max(max(cover_object.^2))/sum(sum((cover_objectwatermarked_image_round).^2)); 
psnr=10*log10(xsz);
```

and here is the error i am getting:

```
Error using ==> mrdivide
Input arguments must be 2-D.

Error in ==> emb at 33
xsz=mc*nc*max(max(cover_object.^2))/sum(sum((cover_object-watermarked_image_round).^2));
```

Edit 1:To link java with matlab I have used an open source,Matlab Control google code,run this code from the command line javac Dwtembed.java. It will be clear if you copy paste the below code and check,you will understand what I am actually trying to do

```
import matlabcontrol.*;
class Dwtembed
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws MatlabConnectionException, MatlabInvocationException
{
        //Create a proxy, which we will use to control MATLAB
        MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory();
        MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy();

        proxy.eval("file_name='lena.bmp';"); 
    proxy.eval("cover_object=double(imread(file_name));"); 
    proxy.eval("mc=size(cover_object,1);"); 
    proxy.eval("nc=size(cover_object,2);"); 
    proxy.eval("file_name='dmg2.bmp';"); 
    proxy.eval("message=double(imread(file_name));"); 
    proxy.eval("mm=size(message,1);"); 
    proxy.eval("nm=size(message,2);"); 
    proxy.eval("[ca,ch,cv,cd]=dwt2(cover_object,'haar');"); 
    proxy.eval("ca1=ca;"); 

    proxy.eval("qiangdu=1;"); 

    proxy.eval("for i=1:nm"); 
            proxy.eval("for j=1:nm"); 
                proxy.eval("if(message(i,j)==0)"); 
                    proxy.eval("ca1(i,j)=ca(i,j)+qiangdu;"); 
                proxy.eval("end"); 
            proxy.eval("end"); 
    proxy.eval("end"); 

    proxy.eval("watermarked_image=idwt2(ca1,ch,cv,cd,'haar');"); 
    proxy.eval("watermarked_image_round=round(watermarked_image);"); 
    proxy.eval("watermarked_image_uint8=uint8(watermarked_image_round);"); 
    proxy.eval("imshow(watermarked_image_uint8);"); 

    proxy.eval("figure(2);");
    proxy.eval("imshow(watermarked_image_uint8,[]);");
    proxy.eval("title('watermarked image');");
    proxy.eval("imwrite(watermarked_image_uint8,'dwt_watermarked.bmp','bmp');"); 
    proxy.eval("xsz=mc*nc*max(max(cover_object.^2))./sum(sum((cover_object-watermarked_image_round).^2));"); 
    proxy.eval("psnr=10*log10(xsz);");



        //Disconnect the proxy from MATLAB
        proxy.disconnect();
}
}
```

Comment: `/` is **matrix division**.  You probably want `./`.

Comment: This works when programming inside Matlab,but when I use the same code outside Matlab that is with Java I am getting the following error: `Error: At least one END is missing: the statement may begin here.`  I do not know why this happens.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth please repond to my previous comment

Comment: I don't understand; none of that code is Java.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes it is not Java,but I am trying to link Java and Matlab,so when I try to link this code,using it in java swing gui,that can basically be done using an open source Matlab Control program,Matlab gives me the above error,what should I do?

Comment: How are you "linking this code"?  Can you get a simpler example to work successfully?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I have show the linking part in the Edit1 version,I hope it makes my problem clear to understand from the code given.

Comment: To be honest, this is really a different question topic.  You should probably re-title this question, or create a new question about this new problem.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth as suggested by you I have asked it in a different question,here is the[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176709/issues-in-using-matlab-control-google-code).I hope to get help