# Issues in using Matlab Control google code

Tags: java, matlab

To link java with matlab I have used an open source,Matlab Control google code
I am getting this error:`Error: At least one END is missing: the statement may begin here.`

Run this code from the command line javac Dwtembed.java.
 It will be clear if you copy paste the below code and check,you will understand what I am actually trying to do.I really hope to get some help for this issue.

```
import matlabcontrol.*;
class Dwtembed
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MatlabConnectionException,          MatlabInvocationException
    {
        //Create a proxy, which we will use to control MATLAB
        MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory();
        MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy();

        proxy.eval("file_name='lena.bmp';"); 
        proxy.eval("cover_object=double(imread(file_name));"); 
        proxy.eval("mc=size(cover_object,1);"); 
        proxy.eval("nc=size(cover_object,2);"); 
        proxy.eval("file_name='dmg2.bmp';"); 
        proxy.eval("message=double(imread(file_name));"); 
        proxy.eval("mm=size(message,1);"); 
        proxy.eval("nm=size(message,2);"); 
        proxy.eval("[ca,ch,cv,cd]=dwt2(cover_object,'haar');"); 
        proxy.eval("ca1=ca;"); 

        proxy.eval("qiangdu=1;"); 

        proxy.eval("for i=1:nm"); 
            proxy.eval("for j=1:nm"); 
                proxy.eval("if(message(i,j)==0)"); 
                    proxy.eval("ca1(i,j)=ca(i,j)+qiangdu;"); 
                proxy.eval("end"); 
            proxy.eval("end"); 
        proxy.eval("end"); 

        proxy.eval("watermarked_image=idwt2(ca1,ch,cv,cd,'haar');"); 
        proxy.eval("watermarked_image_round=round(watermarked_image);"); 
        proxy.eval("watermarked_image_uint8=uint8(watermarked_image_round);"); 
        proxy.eval("imshow(watermarked_image_uint8);"); 

        proxy.eval("figure(2);");
        proxy.eval("imshow(watermarked_image_uint8,[]);");
        proxy.eval("title('watermarked image');");
        proxy.eval("imwrite(watermarked_image_uint8,'dwt_watermarked.bmp','bmp');"); 
        proxy.eval("xsz=mc*nc*max(max(cover_object.^2))./sum(sum((cover_object-watermarked_image_round).^2));"); 
        proxy.eval("psnr=10*log10(xsz);");



    //Disconnect the proxy from MATLAB
    proxy.disconnect();
   }
}
```

Comment: So on which line does it indicate that the statement might begin? Is it the `if` statement?

Comment: @jerad thanks for your comment,but I really don't know,it does not mention the line number

Comment: @jerad did you try to execute the code and are you getting the same error?

Comment: No, I don't have Java. But since the error said the problematic statement may begin "here" i assumed it would give an indication of where "here" is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't `eval` the `for`s and `if`s like that, as `for i=1:nm` is not a valid MATLAB statement on its own. The things you `eval` need to be complete MATLAB statements.

Try putting the entirety of the `for` or `if` statement in a single `eval`.

Comment: Thanks for you response,I tried doing what you said but its giving errors.This is what i have done:`proxy.eval("for i=1:nm 
         for j=1:nm 
             if(message(i,j)==0) 
                ca1(i,j)=ca(i,j)+qiangdu; 
             end 
         end 
    end");`

Comment: OK, two things: first, the statement you have is still not a valid MATLAB command. You would need to put semicolons in to separate statements: `for i=1:nm for j=1:nm if(message(i,j)==0) ca1(i,j)=ca(i,j)+qiangdu; end; end; end`. Secondly, I think it would likely be much easier for you if you just combined all your MATLAB commands together into a single .m file - call it `myscript.m` for example - and then tried `proxy.eval("myscript");`.

Comment: ,I tried proxy.eval("myscript") as you suggested and it works like magic:)Thankyou very much I never knew about it:)

Comment: If the answer has solved your issue, please mark it as accepted, as it helps other users to find it.